# PuLP Linux Exec Format error

Tags: python, linux, python-2.7, ubuntu

When trying to run `PuLP` using `Geany` with `Python 2.7`, I get the following error. Any ideas how I can solve it?
Using `ubuntu` on a `samsung chromebook`.

Traceback (most recent call last):

```
 File "Assign1Q2.py", line 104, in <module>
    prob.solve()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PuLP-1.5.6-py2.7.egg/pulp/pulp.py", line 1619, in solve
    status = solver.actualSolve(self, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PuLP-1.5.6-py2.7.egg/pulp/solvers.py", line 1283, in actualSolve
    return self.solve_CBC(lp, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PuLP-1.5.6-py2.7.egg/pulp/solvers.py", line 1341, in solve_CBC
    stderr = pipe)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 679, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1249, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception
OSError: [Errno 8] Exec format error


------------------
(program exited with code: 1)
Press return to continue
```